# mysql - Finding count of 0 when using joined tables

Tags: mysql, join

**EDIT** I've put up an sqlfiddle with this schema here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0726f2. I'm trying to select customers 3, 4, 5, 6.

Consider a db with three tables:

```
customers
---------
id

seats
-----
id
buyer_id (fk to customers)
flight_id

flights
-------
id
datetime (This is the UTC time of the flight)
```

**I'm trying to find customers who *have not* booked seats on any flight in March.**

This query provides a list of customers who have not booked seats on any flight:

```
SELECT customers.id, count(seats.id) as seat_count FROM `customers` 
LEFT JOIN `seats` ON `seats`.`buyer_id` = `customers`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `flights` ON `flights`.`id` = `seats`.`flight_id` 
GROUP BY customers.id
HAVING seat_count=0
```

I tried this query to find a list of customers who have not booked seats on any flight *in March*

```
SELECT customers.id, count(seats.id) as seat_count FROM `customers` 
LEFT JOIN `seats` ON `seats`.`buyer_id` = `customers`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `flights` ON `flights`.`id` = `seats`.`flight_id` 
WHERE flights.datetime >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
AND flights.datetime <=   '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY customers.id
HAVING seat_count=0
```

But it returns an empty list. I understand why: I'm selecting a list of customers who have booked seats in March then finding customers in that list who have not booked seats. Clearly an empty set.

Likewise with adding this to the WHERE clause

```
AND seats.is is null
```

I can't figure a proper way to do this.

I've tried:

- Flipping the JOINs every which way
- Using a subquery in the LEFT JOIN statement. Performance was prohibitively bad.
- Trying `SELECT customers.id from customers where id not in ([above query])` MySql uses a correlated subquery and performance is also prohibitively awful.

Because this is wrapped up in a larger search feature, I can't come at this from another direction (selecting from seats and going from there, for example). Schema changes are not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll try and work up an sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` like

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM seats 
  INNER JOIN flights ON flights.id = seats.flight_id
  WHERE flights.datetime >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
  AND flights.datetime <=   '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
  AND seats.buyer_id = customers.id
)
```

[here is a corresponding SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f45af/1).

By the way you should at least add an index on `seats.buyer_id`, since this is a column you need to join on. With the named index the execution plan does not look that bad.

Comment: Sorry must have missed it in the fiddle. Our db is indexed correctly. I'll give this a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
SELECT customers.id, count(seats.id) as seat_count FROM `seats` 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM flights WHERE DATE(flights.datetime) >= '2014-03-01'
AND DATE(flights.datetime) <='2014-04-01') `flights` ON `flights`.`id` = `seats`.`flight_id` 
RIGHT JOIN customers ON customers.id=seats.buyer_id
GROUP BY customers.id
HAVING seat_count=0
```

here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0726f2/18)

here's another way to do it:

```
SELECT customers.id FROM customers WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT seats.buyer_id FROM seats
INNER JOIN `flights` ON `flights`.`id` = `seats`.`flight_id` 
WHERE flights.datetime >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
AND flights.datetime <=   '2014-04-01 00:00:00')
```

second [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0726f2/27)

Comment: Sorry, but because this is wrapped up a larger search feature, I can't select on a seats. Thanks.

Comment: @gmoore didn't really understand what's your issue with the first query, you know more... added another way to do it, don't if it could work for you...